Global installation of packages not working in bun
I recently migrated from pnpm to Bun on windows . It works fine for me for every other task just installing local packages , build etc but when i tried to install surge globally but i receive the following error
bun add v1.1.17 (bb66bba1)
Error: InvalidNPMLockfile
Invalid NPM package-lock.json
In a release build, this would ignore and do a fresh install.
Aborting

I tried looking up solutions such as configuring the path but couldnt really find much useful information
